# How to iterate over each row in a dataframe

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have a dataframe which holds various information about a wrestling match. I have grouped the dataframe on the title as I only require the title, gender and duration. the dataframe is 32 rows.

I have declared the information as follows

```
title = df['Title']
duration = df['Duration']
gender = df['Gender']
```

and use a for loop

```
for x in df.index:
print("test")
```

Which does test 32 times as I would expect.

But why is it that when I try to put

```
print(test+gender)
```

if prints out 32 rows 32 times (as if it does the for loop 32 times)

How can I just get the for loop to happen once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do:

```
for x in df.index:
    print(gender[x])
```

Without the `[x]` part, `gender` is a series of 32 rows.